# SharePoint2013 Configuration wizard has stopped working, after windows update

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, cumulative-update, configuration-wizard

We use SharePoint 2013 single farm in windows 2012 R2 standard. Recently Windows has been updated and after that, while trying to open SharePoint central admin getting this following error "SharePoint2013 Configuration wizard has stopped working". I found that cumulative update for **SharePoint2013 KB3191886 installs failed**. I have tried to install many time and no luck.Please suggest me to work SharePoint

[image: SharePoint2013 Configuration wizard has stopped working]

Comment: Did you check event viewer?

Comment: Even, event viewer is not able to open, getting the following error while open the event viewer "MMC could not create the snap-in".

Comment: Try running "system file checker tool" to fix it.

Comment: Why I'm telling you to fix the "Event Viewer" is; we might get good, proper error on why psconfig is failing. Try method in http://troubleshooter.xyz/wiki/fix-mmc-could-not-create-the-snap-in/

Comment: Hi Karthik Thanks for your reply, I think total server messed up. Could not open Server Manager too. But I'm sure this all because of Windows Update. After Windows update only I'm getting this errors.

Comment: you can very well uninstall the update from that machine and try it.

Comment: I guess your windows would not be lower version of sharePoint. Try Downloading the updated version. hope this is helpful
Thank ypu

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command in SharePoint Shell (run as admin)

```
PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures
```

Answer (score -1):

Try re-installing SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score -1):

Follow below steps, it may help you:

1. Click Run to start the installation immediately.
2. Click Save to copy the download to your computer for installation at a later time.